# .htaccess not working on my webserver (404 - not found) how to fix?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, lighttpd

My `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine on

# Rewrite /foo/bar to /foo/bar.php
RewriteRule ^([^.?]+)$ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]

# NOTE! FOR APACHE ON WINDOWS: Add [NC] to RewriteCond like this:
# RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} "^[^ ]* .*?\.php[? ].*$" [NC]
```

The `.htaccess` simply removes the PHP extension,

http://mywebsite.com:8080/page.php

so i can do:

http://mywebsite.com:8080/page

But on my new webserver it just does not work for me, I get error on every page:

> 404 - Not Found

What should i change in the Apache `httpd.conf`?

My `httpd.conf` file:

```
ServerRoot "/data/data/ru.kslabs.ksweb/components/httpd"

TypesConfig /data/data/ru.kslabs.ksweb/components/httpd/conf/mime.types

LoadModule fastcgi_module modules/mod_fastcgi.so

AddHandler php5-fcgi .php
Action php5-fcgi /php5-fcgi
Alias /php5-fcgi /data/data/ru.kslabs.ksweb/components/php/sbin/php-cgi
FastCgiExternalServer /data/data/ru.kslabs.ksweb/components/php/sbin/php-cgi -socket /data/data/ru.kslabs.ksweb/php.sock -idle-timeout 100 -pass-header Authorization

#begin_hosts (do not remove this label!)
Include /data/user/0/ru.kslabs.ksweb/components/httpd/conf/localhost_host.conf
#end_hosts (do not remove this label!)

ServerName localhost

<Files ".ht*">
Require all denied
</Files>

ErrorLog "/mnt/sdcard/ksweb/log/apache/error_log"

LogLevel debug

<IfModule log_config_module>
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common

<IfModule logio_module>
  LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %I %O" combinedio
</IfModule>

CustomLog "/mnt/sdcard/ksweb/log/apache/access_log" common

</IfModule>

#<IfModule headers_module>
#    RequestHeader unset Proxy early
#</IfModule>

StartServers 3
MinSpareServers 3
MaxSpareServers 5
MaxRequestsPerChild 200
```

UPDATE:

The admin of the webserver app wrote in 2012:

(http://kslabs.ru/new-2-63-version-of-ksweb/)

```
Hello!

Lighttpd does not support “.htaccess”.

Rules for “mod_rewrite” are processed in the configuration file of the server – “lighttpd.conf” (http://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/lighttpd/wiki/Docs_ModRewrite).

You can easily find how to do this in the Internet. You also can easily to find ready-made settings for Joomla for lighttpd server. Thank you.
```

This is an old response to someone who asked a similar question,

meaning that the content of the .htaccess should be added in lighttpd.conf?

Comment: Enable rewrite log: [How to debug Apache mod\_rewrite](//stackoverflow.com/q/9632852). And that's a horrific way to hide php extensions, btw. At least check for existence, before blindly mapping it.

Comment: @mario I changed LogLevel debug to LogLevel warn rewrite:trace8, What should I do now?

Comment: Look at the log for rewrites happening or not.

Comment: @mario Not listed there, I also tried with phpinfo(); It does not seem to exist. But on the site of the webserver app admin write something down, I update the post and tell me if it's related